# Using command lines with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, input, command-line

I am trying to compile and run this program by using eclipse. How do I do this?
I cant include the command line in the program. how do i use eclipse to run the program by using this command line??
I know theres another way of making the program by using Scanner but how do i run this one properly??? 
Cant post an image. Just joined.

**INPUTTING FROM A FILE**

```
Display a text file.
/*To use this program, specify the name
of the file that you want to see.
For example, to see a file called TEST.TXT,
use the following command line.
java ShowFile TEST.TXT */

import java.io.*;
class ShowFile {
public static void main(String args[])
throws IOException
{
int i;
FileInputStream fin;
try {
fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
} catch(FileNotFoundException exc) {
System.out.println("File Not Found");
return;
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
System.out.println("Usage: ShowFile File");
return;
}
// read bytes until EOF is encountered
do {
i = fin.read();
if(i != -1) System.out.print((char) i);
} while(i != -1);
fin.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your program, Hover over to **Run As** and Click **Run Configurations**
You will see a dialog box, now click on Arguments tab and specify the command line arguments.
[image: Eclipse Command Line Args]

Comment: no i dont want to specify a command line ARGUMENT. I'm supposed to make the program execute by using the command line. Thats what I think. How do i tell this program where to look for the specified file?
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yup exactly. thats the problem.

Comment: So you are having trouble specifying the file?? Just put the file inside the project folder i.e one step above the src folder,, SRC folder is the place where java classes are stored.

Comment: i did but how do i specify it in the programs code?

Comment: The filename is meant to be given at the runtime through command line args read the comment

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, but to view the output of your program in the **console**:

You can do:
`Window > Show View > Console`

If you want to you want to compile from the command line you can use [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: I am currently studying about Using I/O in Java. This program is supposed to show (what i think) is text entered in a txt file. however whenever i run it it displays file not found. (the error is caught by the exception FileNotFoundException). how am i supposed to tell the program where the file is located?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the file is not in your working directory, you must use the absolute file path to avoid FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Also, `FileInputStream` is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your program, Hover over to Run As and Click Run Configurations You will see a dialog box, now click on Arguments tab and specify the command line arguments.

On Program Arguments simply write *file name OR file Address* **No need to write java ShowFile** in your case it will be **TEST.TXT** .

**Note : Make sure that TEST.TXT file is in your project folder**